# how to print in color a selected element from input

Tags: python, colorama

I have a list of data (extracted from a .cv) and I want to print a list of average with the inputed data in other color. I was able to do everything, but the color is messing me up.

Can an angel help me on how to put in this code?
(i just paste the final print part)

```
import colorama
from colorama import Fore, Back, Style

prefage = []

prefcheck = input("Choose a prefecture: ")
print("MINORITY RATIO IN DESCENDING ORDER WITH SELECTED PREFECTURE IN RED")

for pref in range(0, len(prefage)) :  
        print(prefage[pref][0].rjust(10), end="  ")  
        for minor in range(1, len(prefage[0])) :    
            print(prefage[pref][minor].rjust(10))

else:
    print("Sorry, no prefecture with that name.")
```

Before this idea i was just printing the result in a very simple way:

```
    for x in prefage:
        if prefcheck in x:
        print(x)
        break
```

(removed second question)

---

EDIT:
the entire code is this:

```
    import colorama
    from colorama import Fore, Back, Style

    table = []
    f = open("population.csv", "r")
    for line in f :
        line = line.rstrip("\r\n")
        field = line.split(",")
        table.append(field) ##### field is a list
    f.close()

    #AVERAGE AGE MATH FOR EACH PREFECTURE
    agelist = [ "Age" ]
    ag = 2.5
    for i in range(1, len(table[1])) :
        agelist.append(ag)
        ag += 5

    #PRINT AVERAGE AGE LIST
    prefage = []
    for pref in range(1, len(table)) :
        sum = 0
        asum = 0
        ysum = 0

        for age in range(1, len(table[1])):
            sum += int(table[pref][age])
            asum += int(table[pref][age]) * agelist[age]
        average = round(asum / sum, 1)

        for age in range(1, 5):
            ysum += int(table[pref][age])
            yave = round(ysum*100 / sum, 1)   
        prefage.append([(table[pref][0]), str(yave)])

    #SORT AVARAGE IN DESCENDING ORDER
    n = len(prefage)
    while n > 1 :
        for p in range(0, n - 1) :
            if prefage[p][1] < prefage[p+1][1] :
                prefage[p], prefage[p+1] = prefage[p+1], prefage[p]
        n = n -1 

    print("MINORITY RATIO IN DESCENDING ORDER:")
    for pref in range(0, len(prefage)) :  
            print(prefage[pref][0].rjust(10), end="  ")  
            for avnum in range(1, len(prefage[0])) :    
                print(prefage[pref][avnum].rjust(10))

    print()
    prefcheck = input("Choose a prefecture: ")
    for x in prefage:
        if prefcheck in x:
            print(x)
            break

    else:
        print("Sorry, no prefecture with that name")
```

Comment: `print(Fore.RED, x, Fore.RESET)`

Comment: you should as one question on one page.

Comment: to prompt input again you have to run code in some loop - ie. in `while True:`

Comment: or better `print( f"{Fore.RED}{x}{Fore.RESET}" )` because it doesn't add spaces between elements.

Comment: and if you want to justify then use f-string `print( f"{Fore.RED}{x:>10}{Fore.RESET}" )`

Comment: you put full code but we don't have your file csv to run it and see how it work and what it display. Better put example data directly in list `prefage = [...]`

Answer (score 1):

You can do

```
print(Fore.RED, x, Fore.RESET)
```

but it will add spaces between value and colors so better use `f-string`

```
print( f"{Fore.RED}{x}{Fore.RESET}" )
```

And then you can use `f-string` to justify: `{x:>10}`, `{x:<10}`, `{x:^10}`

---

```
from colorama import Fore, Back, Style

x = 10
print('|', x, '|')  # without color
print('|', Fore.RED, x, Fore.RESET, '|')  # with color
print( f'|{Fore.RED}{x}{Fore.RESET}|' )  # f-string

print( f'|{Fore.RED}{x:>10}{Fore.RESET}|' )
print( f'|{Fore.RED}{x:<10}{Fore.RESET}|' )
print( f'|{Fore.RED}{x:^10}{Fore.RESET}|' )
```

Result:

```
| 10 |    # without colors
|  10  |  # with colors
|10|      # f-string with colors

|        10|  # x:>10
|10        |  # x:<10
|    10    |  # x:^10
```

---

You can also use variable to set justify - with nested `{ }`

```
max_len = 10

print( f'|{Fore.RED}{x:^{max_len}}{Fore.RESET}|' )
```

---

**EDIT:**

If you want bright colors then you can add `Style.BRIGHT` and remove it with `Style.NORMAL`

```
print( f'|{Fore.RED+Style.BRIGHT}{x:^10}{Fore.RESET+Style.NORMAL}|' )
```

You may also use variables

```
start_color = Fore.RED+Style.BRIGHT
reset_color = Fore.RESET+Style.NORMAL

print( f'|{start_color}{x:^10}{reset_color}|' )
```

So you can use it with `if/else`

```
if prefcheck in x:
    start_color = Fore.RED+Style.BRIGHT
    reset_color = Fore.RESET+Style.NORMAL
else:
    start_color = ''
    reset_color = ''

print( f'|{start_color}{x:^10}{reset_color}|' )
```

Or define shorter names

```
CR = Fore.RED+Style.BRIGHT   # Color Red
CG = Fore.GREEN+Style.BRIGHT # Color Green
CX = Fore.RESET+Style.NORMAL # Color reset

if prefcheck in x:
    start_color = CR
    reset_color = CX
else:
    start_color = ''
    reset_color = ''

print( f'|{start_color}{x:^10}{reset_color}|' )
```

Comment: Thank you for the one question tip and for the lecture of colorama, really appreciated.

Comment: But I have a more straight forward question. I think my question was not clear enough. I want to print the list with ONLY the inputed element in red. So the person is prompted, she writes the prefecture and it prints the entire list with onlly the '''prefcheck''' in red. Can you help me with that?

Comment: you have all in your question to do it - `for x in prefage: if prefcheck in x: print(x)` and use color in this `print()`. That's all.

Comment: and if you need it in `for pref in  ...` then use `if prefcheck in x: print(color, ..., reset) else print(...)` in place of `print(...)`